# Missing items using simpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this XML output. I am feeding it into simpleXML in PHP. I am trying to retrieve all stands, plots, and trees. For some reason, I am only getting the plots in the first stand and not the second. The same for trees, I am only getting the tree backs in the first stand. The code that I am using is posted below the XML. I have tried many different ways to hit these sections and no luck .

```
 <Tracts>
 <tract>
  <tract>tract1</tract> 
 <county>Glynn</county> 
<state>GA</state> 
<name>Garrett</name> 
<owner>Bob</owner> 
<date>Nov 6, 2011</date> 
 <stands>
 <Stand>
 <stand>1</stand> 
  <age>12</age> 
  <thinned>true</thinned> 
  <thinYear>2007</thinYear> 
  <species>PL Lob</species> 
 <cruiser>me</cruiser> 
<hPlotSize>50th Acre</hPlotSize> 
<pPlotSize>50th Acre</pPlotSize> 
<treeType>None</treeType> 
<fixedOrPrism>5</fixedOrPrism> 
<plots>
<Plot>
 <plotNum>5</plotNum> 
 <pPMStems>12</pPMStems> 
 <hPMStems>12</hPMStems> 
 <pPMHt>12</pPMHt> 
 <hPMHt>12</hPMHt> 
 <pMStems>12</pMStems> 
 <hMStems>12</hMStems> 
  <pMHt>0</pMHt> 
 <hMHt>12</hMHt> 
 <pHtCrown>0</pHtCrown> 
<trees>
<Tree>
<treeNum>3</treeNum> 
<DBH>18</DBH> 
<species>LOB</species> 
<type>CROP</type> 
<merch>12</merch> 
<htToCrown>9</htToCrown> 
<merchLogs>1.0</merchLogs> 
<defects>
<string>CRON</string> 
<string>SCRAPE</string> 
</defects>
</Tree>
<Tree>
 <treeNum>3</treeNum> 
 <DBH>18</DBH> 
 <species>LOB</species> 
 <type>CROP</type> 
<merch>12</merch> 
<htToCrown>9</htToCrown> 
<merchLogs>1.0</merchLogs> 
<defects>
  <string>CRON</string> 
<string>SCRAPE</string> 
</defects>
</Tree>
<Tree>
<treeNum>3</treeNum> 
<DBH>18</DBH> 
<species>LOB</species> 
<type>CROP</type> 
<merch>12</merch> 
<htToCrown>9</htToCrown> 
<merchLogs>1.0</merchLogs> 
<defects>
<string>CRON</string> 
<string>SCRAPE</string> 
</defects>
</Tree>
</trees>
</Plot>
<Plot>
<plotNum>9</plotNum> 
<pPMStems>3</pPMStems> 
<hPMStems>3</hPMStems> 
<pPMHt>3</pPMHt> 
<hPMHt>3</hPMHt> 
<pMStems>3</pMStems> 
<hMStems>3</hMStems> 
<pMHt>0</pMHt> 
<hMHt>3</hMHt> 
<pHtCrown>0</pHtCrown> 
<trees /> 
 </Plot>
</plots>
</Stand>
<Stand>
 <stand>2</stand> 
<age>20</age> 
<thinned>false</thinned> 
<thinYear>0</thinYear> 
 <species>PL Lob</species> 
 <cruiser>me</cruiser> 
<hPlotSize>50th Acre</hPlotSize> 
<pPlotSize>10th Acre</pPlotSize> 
<treeType>Fixed</treeType> 
<fixedOrPrism>100%</fixedOrPrism> 
<plots>
<Plot>
<plotNum>2</plotNum> 
<pPMStems>12</pPMStems> 
<hPMStems>20</hPMStems> 
<pPMHt>32</pPMHt> 
<hPMHt>16</hPMHt> 
<pMStems>21</pMStems> 
<hMStems>7</hMStems> 
<pMHt>0</pMHt> 
<hMHt>13</hMHt> 
<pHtCrown>0</pHtCrown> 
<trees>
<Tree>
  <treeNum>1</treeNum> 
  <DBH>10</DBH> 
  <species>LOB</species> 
   <type>CROP</type> 
  <merch>12</merch> 
  <htToCrown>16</htToCrown> 
  <merchLogs>4.5</merchLogs> 
 <defects>
  <string>CRON</string> 
   <string>OTHER</string> 
</defects>
 </Tree>
 </trees>
 </Plot>
</plots>
 </Stand>
 </stands>
 </tract>
</Tracts>

  foreach($xml->tract->stands->Stand->plots->Plot as $plot)
  {
  echo $plot->plotNum;
  }
  echo '<br><br>'; 

  foreach ($xml->tract->stands->Stand->plots->Plot->trees->Tree as $tree) 
  {
  echo $tree->treeNum;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$xml->tract->stands->Stand->plots->Plot` will only ever reference the first `Stand` element - think of the document as a set of nested arrays.

SimpleXML assumes that if you mention an element name without looping or indexing into it, you want the first element of that name. In other words, it's the same as writing `foreach ( $xml->tract[0]->stands[0]->Stand[0]->plots[0]->Plot ) ...`

So you need to nest your foreach loops:

```
foreach($xml->tract->stands->Stand as $stand)
{
   foreach($stand->plots->Plot as $plot)
   {
       echo $plot->plotNum;

       foreach ( $plot->trees->Tree as $tree )
       {
           echo $tree->treeNum;
       }
   }
```

}